# Is there a script to find/extract steganographically hidden files in all images of a directory?

Tags: python, images, cryptography

Is there a script to detect and extract files that were steganographically hidden in images?

It would be best if it was a Python script and scanned for as many methods of steganography as possible. It could also scan for clues that suggest that a file is hidden within an image even if it can't extract it.

---

Scripts that I know of, like stegpy, can only scan single files and not all images within a directory (if not used in script) and often use only one method of detecting/extracting hidden files.

I am not asking about tools to scan individual files. For example, with stegpy one could theoretically use `os.system('stegpy {}'.format(filename))` in a python file or `for file in /path/*; do stegpy "$file"; done` in the console but that doesn't really work and it only scans for one way of hiding files. I'm looking for a script that nicely scans an entire directory using multiple detection-methods with an output like "3 files found: {paths}, extracted files in {path2}".